# What are the two floating circles/rings in The Catacombs?

Tags: dark-souls

In the Catacombs, in the ground-level chamber just before the outside area with the cartwheel skeletons (the one with two bow-wielding skeletons), there are two white, floating circles/rings.

Can anyone tell me what these are and what the are for?

**EDIT:** Here's a screenshot:
[image: floating ring]

This is one of the two rings. The exit on the left of screen takes you to the outside area with the skeleton wheels. The rings are not visible when you first enter this area, but appear after you have cleared the room of enemies. They also don't seem to appear unless you are playing online.

Comment: Would it be possible for you take a screen shot?

Comment: I'll attempt to take a screenshot of my own game soon. In the mean-time, see this Reddit discussion (http://www.reddit.com/r/darksouls/comments/mn0d5/dark_souls_white_ring_miracle_synergies_i_think/), which includes a link to a screenshot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe these are the resonance areas for the [Way of White](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Way_of_White) covenant.  If you cast a miracle there, it will have [increased effectiveness](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/miracle-synergy) under certain circumstances.  It's tied into the online/multiplayer aspect of Dark Souls, and I'm not sure it's been fully explored and documented.

Comment: This seems to be the general concensus, but there doesn't seem to be any definitive answer.

Answer (score 2):

Those are [resonance circles](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/miracle-synergy), which increase the power and effectiveness of certain miracles when they are cast near the circles. They are not specifically tied to any covenant (as the first answer incorrectly states) - any player in any covenant may see resonance circles. They can randomly appear where other players in your multiplayer "web" cast miracles. To see whether or not a miracle will be boosted, check whether the icon of the miracle (when equipped in your spell slot) has the same symbol on it. Standing near multiple circles will increase the boost, up to a maximum of 3 circles. [The Ring of the Sun Princess](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/ring-of-the-sun-princess) acts as a constant, portable resonance circle. Wearing the ring and standing near a resonance circle provides the same effect as standing near three resonance circles.